# how to replace data in one table iF certain columns are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have pulled the following data and would like to replace x,y,z from(2b24d001) with the x,y,z of (2b25d001)  based on same equal hole_no column (e.g if hole_no for 2b24d001 = 2b25d001.

```
hole_id     block_id    xcollar     ycollar  zcollar  HOLE_NO
2B24D001B01 2B24D001    4382.693    3858.52  109.725    B01
2B25D001B01 2B25D001    5372.693    3358.52  392.5      B01
2B25D001B02 2B25D001    7383.893    9356.03  662.5      B02
2B24D001B02 2B24D001    5373.893    3656.03  969.525    B02
2B24D001B03 2B24D001    8876.038    3352.216 399.38     B03
2B25D001B03 2B25D001    5376.038    3752.216 392.5      B03
1B13D078B03 1B13D078    1628.253    3956.26  692.53     B03
1B12D078B03 1B13D078    1828.253    3556.26  392.53     B03
```

Comment: So, what is your question here? You've stated what you want to do, but haven't asked anything (it's really important to ask a question when you're posting one). What have you tried so far? What were the issues/errors you had?

Comment: Post the expected output for that data if you are unable to explain in words.

Comment: How do you replace the xyz of 2b24 with xyz of those in 2b25 if hole_no are equal.

Comment: hole_id     block_id    xcollar     ycollar  zcollar  HOLE_NO
2B24D001B01 2B24D001    5372.693    3358.52  392.725    B01
2B25D001B01 2B25D001    5372.693    3358.52  392.725      B01 @salman above table is expected answer for  Hole_NO B01

Comment: @Uno, how do you decide which one to keep. hole_id 2B24D001B01  or hole_id 2B25D001B01  for HOLE_NO B01

Comment: @VenkataramanR asked by the end user. This is not usual requirement, just special request for this specific holes.

Comment: Please put the updates in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52255107/edit) it. Especially with data, as it is often useless when posted in a comment as it can't be formatted.

Comment: @Uno, ok. but, if there are two hold_id for a HOLE_NO (say B01), which one do you choose for hole_id for updation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `update`/`join`, but like this:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET xcollar = t2.xcollar,
        ycollar = t2.ycollar,
        zcollar = t2.zcollar
    FROM T t1 JOIN
         T t2
         ON t1.hole_no = t2.hole_no
    WHERE t1.block_id = '2b24d001' AND
          t2.block_id = '2b25d001';
```

Comment: @ gorden Linoff  it gives me an error of  ''Msg 8154, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The table 'tablename' is ambiguous.''

Comment: @uno . . . `t1` is a table alias that is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number()

```
select * from
 (
 select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by HOLE_NO order by case when block_id='2b24d001' then 0 case when block_id='2b25d001' then 1 end desc ) as rn 
form tablet
) as t
where rn=1
) t1 innerjoin tablet t2 on t1.block_id=t2.block_id
```

or you can use cte in same thing

```
with cte as
(

select * from
    (
    select *,row_number() over(partition by HOLE_NO order by case when block_id='2b24d001' then 0 case when block_id='2b25d001' then 1 end desc ) as rn 
    form tablet
    ) as t
    where rn=1
) select * from cte inner join tablet t2 on cte.block_id=t2.block_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you seem to want to do `UPDATE JOIN`, `JOIN` base on the  `REPLACE (hole_id,block_id,'')`.

```
UPDATE t1
SET xcollar = t2.xcollar,
    ycollar = t2.ycollar,
    zcollar = t2.zcollar
FROM T t1 JOIN T t2
    ON REPLACE (t1.hole_id,t1.block_id,'') = REPLACE (t2.hole_id,t2.block_id,'')
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be022540f957d11d5c7507a90506fe21)